# PowerShell trouble storing Windows Passphrase into variable

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble finding out how to store my Windows Passphrase into a log.txt file. My guess is that I'm using this part wrong "name=`"$SSID`" "?

My code:

```
$SSID = (get-netconnectionProfile).Name;

$PASSPHRASE = $(netsh.exe wlan show profiles name=`"$SSID`" key=clear | Select-String -pattern ".*Key Content.*:(.*)" -allmatches);

Start-Transcript -Path "$home\Log.txt";

netsh.exe wlan show interface;

write-output $PASSPHRASE;

Stop-Transcript;
```

Content of $SSID:

```
$SSID = (get-netconnectionProfile).Name
write-output $SSID
My_Network_SSID_HARDCODED
My_Network_SSID_HARDCODED
```

FYI, when I replace `"$SSID`" and hardcode it ti my actual SSID, i do get my passphrase, so I guess I'm failing to store my key into the $passphrase.

Working:

```
$PASSPHRASE = $(netsh.exe wlan show profiles name="My_Network_SSID_HARDCODED" key=clear | Select-String -pattern ".*Key Content.*:(.*)" -allmatches)

write-output $PASSPHRASE

    Key Content            : 1234567890
```

Googling for Powershel Variables

Comment: `Get-NetConnectionProfile` probably returns more than one network profile. What do you see if you run `Get-NetConnectionProfile` in an interactive shell?

Answer (score 1):

`Get-NetConnectionProfile` returns profile information for any active network interface, not just wireless networks.

A more reliable way to only get wifi profiles is to use `netsh wlan show networks` for that part too:

```
$wlanKeys = netsh wlan show networks |ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^SSID \d+\s*:\s*(.*)$') {
        $ssidName = $Matches[1]
        netsh wlan show profile "name=`"${ssidName}`"" key=clear |ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -match 'Key Content\s*:\s*(.*)$') {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Name = $ssidName
                    Key = $Matches[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$wlanKeys` will hold the ssid and password for each connected wifi network (however many found)

Comment: This works perfect in Powershell, does exactly what I need. Problem is I'm running it from a Flipper Zero with BADUSB which only support Duckyscript 1.0. Duckyscript 3.0 can do IF/ELSE but 1.0 doesn't. At this point in time, it doesn't look like the Flipper will support 3.0 anytime soon (if ever since this is HAK5). Is there a way to write you’re block of code in a one-liner?